# Print custom header parameter's value in nginx access log

Tags: nginx

I have a situation where consumer is passing a service a custom header parameter "Userid", I am trying to log it to nginx access log.
This is what I tried and it is not working-

```
log_format customm '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "[uid=$upstream_http_Userid]"';
access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log  customm;
```

I also attempted these - $upstream_http_x_Userid $upstream_Userid $Userid $upstream_http_userid $upstream_userid $upstream_http_x_userid $userid and none of them worked. So I wanted to check what I am doing wrong and what is the right way to log this value to access log.

Comment: If it is a request header it should be just `$http_userid` https://nginx.org/r/$http_

Comment: @AlexeyTen This worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. If you could convert your comment to Answer I can show my gratitude by accepting the answer as the one that resolved the issue. Thanks for taking your time to respond.